# Purpose of date.getTime in the expires flag of the cookie?

Tags: javascript

I have a line of code that sets a cookie with an expiry date that looks like this.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*365);
var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
```

What I'm trying to do is understand what each number represents. I know thats its just adding milliseconds to the time object but what does each one represent is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1000 milliseconds in a second

60 seconds in a minute

60 minutes in an hour

24 hour in a day

365 days in a year

So, you'll get the quantity of milliseconds in a year.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date(); // date object (now on this computer)

date.setTime( // change the time
date.getTime() // now in milliseconds since 1970

+ 1000 // milliseconds in a second
* 60 // seconds in a minut
* 60 // minutes in an hour
* 24 // hours in a day
* 365 // approximate days in a year. Total ~ number of milliseconds in a year
);
var expires = "; expires=" + 
date.toGMTString(); // format the time to what the cookie likes
```

Please read

- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [toGMTString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)

for more information

Answer (score 1):

1000 millicesonds times 60 seconds times 60 minutes times 24 hours times 365 days. It's a year.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this:

```
1000*60*60*24*365

1000 // Converts milliseconds into seconds
60 // Converts seconds into minutes
60 // Convert minutes into hours
24 // Converts hours into days
365 // Convert days into year
```

Answer (score 1):

1000 milliseconds per second,
60 seconds per minute,
60 minutes per hour,
24 hours in a day,
365 days in a year,

So it is adding the number of milliseconds in a year, advancing the time by a year